# htaccess 301 for new page name across all subdomains

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

I'm running a WordPress multisite network with multiple sites across subdomains.  I need to change the url of a page that is copied across all of them and setup  redirect for the old URL.

Examples:
`xyz.site.com/about-our-group` redirect to `xyz.site.com/about`
`abc.site.com/about-our-group` redirect to `abc.site.com/about`

How can I achieve this in my .htaccess file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this rule as very first rule just below `RewriteBase` line:

```
RewriteRule ^about- /about [L,NC,R=301]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Redirect 301 /about-our-group /about
```